# Join tables in NHibernate without mapping

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I have the following two objects:

**User**

```
class User {
    public int role;
}
```

**Role**

```
class Role {
    public int id;
    public string name;
}
```

be note that `role` property inside `User` is `int` and not `Role`, that's our limitations.

I want to join between all the users and each of his role. In the mapping objects there is no reference as you can understand, just a simple type (`int`).

How do I do that join statement?

Comment: Join without object mapping, simply does not fit into ORM == Object-relational mapping! I do seriously advice you: do not use ORM tool for that at all. Really.

Comment: You right, but I'm sure there is a way to do that.

Comment: The JOIN is in ORM world coming from relations. If you won't define relations - among objects, the JOIN cannot be created. Only with hacking... some `CreateSQL` like features. But this is really not the way which you should go. Create relation on C# level (it is really really easy) and map it. NHibernate will then do the difficult for you very easily ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's called a theta join:

```
var a = (from u in session.Query<User>()
        from r in session.Query<Role>()
        where u.role == r.id
        select new { u.Username, Role = r.name }).ToList();
```

Assuming you have a Username property on the User class.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this "theta join" (as I just learned this term) is very handy and let's us not worry about putting in pointless mapping relationships.

WARNING HOWEVER IN USING THIS!!!  This tripped me up a lot.

Adding to the above example...

```
var list = new List<int>( { 2, 3 } ); // pretend in-memory data from something.
var a = 
   (from u in session.Query<User>()
    from x in list
    from r in session.Query<Role>()
    where u.role == r.id
    where r.id == x.id  // pretend list wants to limit to only certain roles.
    select new { u.Username, Role = r.name }).ToList();
```

THIS WILL BOMB with some NotSupported exception.
The trick is that anything coming from NHibernate Session must come LAST. So this alteration WILL work:

```
var a = 
   (from x in list
    from u in session.Query<User>()
    from r in session.Query<Role>()
    where u.role == r.id
    where r.id == x.id  // pretend list wants to limit to only certain roles.
    select new { u.Username, Role = r.name }).ToList();
```

And and BTW, you can use join as well, however you have to make sure if you have any nullable data types, that you use the  .Value  if you are joining to something not-nullable.

```
var a = 
   (from x in list
    from u in session.Query<User>()
    join r in session.Query<Role>() on u.role equals r.id
    where r.id == x.id  // pretend list wants to limit to only certain roles.
    select new { u.Username, Role = r.name }).ToList();
```

And while we're at it, let's say you have a method that has some dynamic condition. In this example the 'list' which could be a list of roles to filter by, but don't filter at all if the list is not there. Well, if you do the `.ToList()` then you are causing this query to execute immediately. But instead you can add a condition and then execute it later:

```
var a = 
    from u in session.Query<User>()
    join r in session.Query<Role>() on u.role equals r.id
    where r.id == x.id  // pretend list wants to limit to only certain roles.
    select new { u.Username, Role = r.name, RoleID = r.id }; // Adding the Role ID into this output.

if (list != null) // assume if the list given is null, that means no filter.
{
    a = a.Where(x => list.Contains(x.RoleID));

    // WARNING. Unfortunately using the "theta" format here will not work. Not sure why.
}

var b = a.ToList(); // actually execute it.
var c = a.Select(x => new { x.Username, x.Role }).ToList() // if you insist on removing that extra RoleID in the output.
```

One last thing.. Sometimes some simple logic will fail when executed in the `select new { .. }` part. I don't have an explanation. In our case the logic was just converting a DB value of a uint to an Enumerator of a model. But to get around that, I just avoided doing that conversion while reading the data but saved the value. Then in a later step, after the data was loaded, I just did the conversion in another LINQ statement.

DISCLAIMER: While I wrote many of these things all the past several weeks, I did not put this code into my compiler to verify 100%.